# How to add wildcard vhost for a website running WHM (and can AutoSSL work?)

Tags: apache, cpanel, virtualhost, whm

I have a multisite running on WHM. I have
mainsite.tld and *.mainsite.tld setup in the folder with a dedicated IP mapped to it.

Now, I need to setup a wildcard virtualhost directive so I can handle the Domains mapped to it (example1.tld, example2.tld, etc)

WHM wont allow me to do this.

Worst, `example1.tld` and `example2.tld` are domains in my account, so the WHM fairy is routing those examples to their `/home/example1/public_html` folder.

Please advise.